# Google Calendar API gives 404 while inserting events to calendar after pods updation.

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api

i integrated google calendar in my iOS application, and insert events from application using this Call " 
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events "
and events inserted sucessfully in my google calendar

i updated pods due to ios 11 now this api 
now it gives this error in response. cant figure it out where the problem is.

ERROR: Invalid value for: Invalid format: \"2017-12-07 07:00:00\" is malformed at \" 07:00:00\

Comment: hii i need help in google calendar how to create event through my app in swift @junaidUmer

Comment: use google api for add event...
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events
this is api u have to hit for adding event to your google primary calendar for more detail visit this link 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: and if you want guidance about how to make request in swift 4 u may take a look at swift documentation or u can email me junaidumer28@gmail.com

Comment: bro how can i connect u @junaidUmer

Comment: i just left my email adress see in comment above

Comment: i have implemented sample code for google calendar by sign in button which is working properly but how will i procceed further any skype id

Comment: could u have some code for creating event

Comment: i m not getting any idea since 15 days

Comment: yes u can contact me on skype jjunaid50 
i am using Alamofire for making request. if u are getting an error while calling api then it may be auth error u have to attach access token in header file

Comment: thnks bro i will ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error prolly is due to wrong time format. Follow the [RFC3339](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) for date time formats. It looks something like:

```
2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00
```

Notice the letter T which stands for [full date/full-time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).